# R - Classify las using a shape

Tags: lidar, lidr

Using lidR
I have LIDAR point cloud and a Shapefile.
I am trying to classify a las file using several polygons that are in the .shp.

Can you help me?

I've try merge_spatial and classify_poi from lidR

Shape Attribute table

[image: 1]

I want to have a Coolum field in the las file with the tree row number

Comment: What code did you used. `cassify_poi` should do the job.

Comment: Can you help me with the code?